# hasProperty returns null

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to identify if the Groovy (actually Grails domain) class has a property with the `hasProperty` method.  It always returns null. `getProperty` founds this. What is the difference between those two methods?

Groovy has the javadoc for the hasProperty , but it's not clear at all.

> Returns true of the implementing MetaClass has a property of the given name
>
> Note that this method will only return true for realised properties and does not take into
>   account implementation of getProperty or propertyMissing

Is this groovy meta protocol bug?

Groovy 2.0.7 from grails 2.2.1 .

Thanks!

Comment: Is that a static property you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasProperty` identifies class properties binded to the metaclass of an object, whereas `getProperty` can be pretty arbitrary: you can write a method to return whatever you want. How can `hasProperty` get into that? Executing `getProperty`? Seems a bit weird to me.

You can override `hasProperty` so it consider whatever logic is in `getProperty`:

```
class Person {
  Map otherProperties = [:]
  def getProperty(String property) {
    otherProperties[property]
  }

  void setProperty(String prop, value) { 
    otherProperties[prop] = value 
  }

  boolean hasProperty(String property) { 
    otherProperties.containsKey(property) 
  }
}

p = new Person()
p.name = "John"
p.age = 40

assert p.hasProperty('name')
assert p.hasProperty('age')
assert !p.hasProperty('dob')
```